# Cursive navigate forward/back word within a comment line

Tags: cursive

Alt-left & Alt-right (the emacs key-bindings that work across many apps in Mac OS, including as I type now into chrome), instead of doing forward and back `word`, go forward and back `form` (i.e. lisp form). 
This is a much higher level navigation, frustrating at first, but actually turns out quite usable because you can just bump one char into a form if you don't want to jump over it, then you can navigate by word within it just fine.

This is fine except within a comment line. There, the usual forward and back word break completely, simply jumping you back to the previous form (comment lines are ignored) or on to the next.

It would be great to be able to make cursive/intellij respect forward/back word within a comment line if possible but I have no idea how to modify this particular behaviour. It seems deeper than just modifying a key binding,  if I'm correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out these keys in cursive/intellij are bound by default as follows (note Alt-right is by default bound to **both** of the below):

[image: key bindings 1]

and

[image: key bindings 1]

The second was overriding the first, the one wanted here.

So by removing the alt binding to make it look like:

[image]

Plus the same for back, it now works as desired :)